# R data.table: detect pattern of values within each group

Tags: r, database, string, data.table, pattern-matching

Say I have a data.table like this:

```
set.seed(10)
data.table(group = rep(c("a","b","c"), each=5), date = rep(1:5,3), value = sample(c(95:105,""),15, replace=TRUE))
```

Within each group, in the value column, I would like to check (in a simple whay) whether there is a ""(empty character), or a group of empty characters, that is both preceded and followed by a value.

So, this is fine: "", 95,103, etc.... (empty character is first within the group), but the patterns below are **examples"missing data" that I would like to detect:**

95, "", 103,... (empty character in the middle)

95, "","", 103... (several empty characters in the middle)

95, 103, ""  (empty character in the end)

So, in the output below, I would be able to get the row/group A, and if there are many groups, I should get all groups (or rows)

```
    group date value
 1:     a    1   105
 2:     a    2   103
 3:     a    3   104
 4:     a    4      
 5:     a    5   101
 6:     b    1   102
 7:     b    2   100
 8:     b    3   101
 9:     b    4    97
10:     b    5   102
11:     c    1   104
12:     c    2   101
13:     c    3   104
14:     c    4    96
15:     c    5   102
```

Edit:
**What I would need do is to select the rows that have the wrong pattern (so empty string(s) in the middle or in the end)**, in order to be able to detect whether there are any errors in a large dataset. So in the table in my example, **the desired output would be the 4th row as it has a "missing value" (an empty character inbetween values)**

```
     group date value
1:     a    4
```

(If there were more unwanted rows, of course, I would like to get all of them)

Comment: No `""` in you data

Comment: What is your desired output, the rows that meet the criteria or the ones that don't?

Comment: @Edward The ones that do (e.g. I want to check whether there are gaps in a large dataset, and ideally there would be zero)

Comment: @arg0naut91 4th row? Otherwise just use different seed number...

Answer (score 1):

In case your data.table is not sorted according to 'date' column you can use the following:

```
DT[order(date), order := c(1:.N) , group]
DT[value == "" & order > 1L]
```

output:

```
   group date value order
1:     a    4           4
```

data is the same as yours:

```
set.seed(10)
DT <- data.table(group = rep(c("a","b","c"), each=5), date = rep(1:5,3), 
                 value = sample(c(95:105,""),15, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't think this would work in case when within a group there is more than one row that have an empty string in the beginning (e.g. 1st, 2nd, and 3rd have an empty string)?

Comment: It will work. You can test with the following example: `DT <- data.table(group = rep(c("a","b"), each=3), date = c(1,2,3), value = c("","","","95","","100"))`

Comment: The answer basically returns all the rows that has an an empty string as 'value' except the first date of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
DT[, rw := rleid(value==""), group]
DT[value=="" & rw>1L]
```

output:

```
   group date value rw
1:     a    4        2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(10)
DT <- data.table(group = rep(c("a","b","c","d"), each=5), 
    date = rep(1:5,4), value = c(sample(c(95:105,""),15, replace=TRUE), c("",2,3,4,5)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I would lite do is to select the rows that have the wrong pattern (so empty string/strings in the middle), in order to be able to detect whether there are any errors in a large dataset.

Comment: can you post your desired output?

Comment: In the DT you created, it would be: 1:     c    5 (15th row of the DT table, which has an empty string as a last value within the group). In the table in my example, it would be the 4th row as it has an empty character inbetween values

Comment: *post* as in type in the desired output in your post as wording is quite vague.

Comment: have also updated my post. the prev ans was because  based on *I would be able to get the row/group A, and if there are many groups, I should get all groups (or rows)*, it seemed like you wanted the whole group

Comment: Done. I have added it to the original question.

Comment: What I meant with row/group is either row or group. This was really unclear, sorry about that.